# if-else path not taken in imports in angular istanbul code coverage report

Tags: angular, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Com(I)ponent({
  selector: 'app-fruit-cake',(E)
  templateUrl: './fruit-cake.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fruit-cake.component.scss'],
})
expo(E)rt class FruitCakeComponent {
  constructor(private _title: Title) {
    _title.setTitle('Cake');
  }
}
```

My code coverage report shows (E): else path not taken. (I): if path not taken.
What does it mean in the context of import statements and decorators?
My code coverage is not reaching to 100% in any of my tests due to this.
How do I rectify it?

Comment: Why export is written like expo(E)rt and Component like Com(I)ponent?

Comment: This is from the coverage report that is generated by Istanbul. (E) and (I) are markers which tell you that else path not taken and if path not taken.

Comment: Please provide the test suite code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to remove:

```
--sourceMap=false
```

Previously, I had added this to help diagnose other issues. So my **test script** in **package.json** looked like this:

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage --sourceMap=false"
```

I changed it to be:

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage"
```

Then, all of my code coverage started reporting correctly. You may also want to verify your **devDependencies** in **package.json**. I am using **Angular 6** so they look like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676221/4695469 below by @JFPicard for the best way to configure this.

Answer (score 20):

For Angular 6, it seems that you need to `"sourceMap": true` to your `test` like this:

```
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "test/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "test/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "codeCoverageExclude": []
      }
```

Comment: with "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.5", working great, thanks !